# simple php route redirection

Tags: php, redirect, routes

so I'm using a certain cloud service to make a simple contact page. it's the only working page in my domain, and it's supposed to be mydomain.com/contact. if the user accesses mydomain.com, it has to be redirected to mydomain.com/contact.

there's a directory called php, this is the root directory of my site. if I create an index.php file and put my contact information there it's okay, but it will obviously only be accessible by mydomain.com. I tried creating a contact folder and moving my index.php to there, but it didn't work. I tried creating a contact folder and placing a contact.php in it with all the code I want and, in the root directory, putting and index.php file with the header function:

```
<? header('Location: contact/contact.php'); ?>
```

and it also did not work. how can I make it so that mydomain.com/contact/ is available?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<?php header('Location: contact/contact.php'); ?>
```

Comment: The reason he provided this answer is because using the shorthand open tag is a configurable PHP option. His answer is hinting that this option may be disabled in one environment but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to not use `<? ?>` unless you enable `short_open_tag` in the ini directive. Your code seems fine, I think the problem is with the php tags. Try using the normal PHP tags `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
<?php header('Location: contact/contact.php'); ?>
```

to be the first line in the file, otherwise it may not work.